# How to create SharedFlow from 2 StateFlow?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 state flows, and I would like to merge thease into 1 state flow. So, until the 2 data change, the viewModel doesn't call a specific function, with which update the shared flow.

The problem is, when I open a dialog, and navigate back, the shared flow get a new value, probably because of the 2 state flows fire.

So my question is, can I somehow achive this behavior, or my whole solution is bad?

ViewModel:

```
private val _selectedMachineComponent = MutableStateFlow<MachineComponentView?>(null)
    val selectedMachineComponent = _selectedMachineComponent.asStateFlow()

    private val _previousManufacture = MutableStateFlow<PreviousManufactureView?>(null)
    val previousManufacture = _previousManufacture.asStateFlow()
    
    private val _defaultStateOfWorkflowBarcode =
        _previousManufacture.combine(_selectedMachineComponent) { f1, f2 ->
            if (f1?.machineComponentUnderManufacture == true || f1?.selectedMachineId.isNullOrEmpty() || f2?.id.isNullOrEmpty()) {

                return@combine null
            }

            val result =
                stateOfWorkflowRepository.getDefaultStateOfWorkflowBarcodes(
                    f1?.selectedMachineId!!, f2?.id!!
                )

            if (result is Result.Success && result.data.isNotEmpty()) {
                return@combine result.data
            }else{
                val msg = if (result is Result.ApiErrorMsg) result.msg else "Sikertelen betöltés"

                showSimpleOkDialog(OkDialogView("Figyelem", msg ?: ""))
            }

            return@combine emptyList()
        }
    val defaultStateOfWorkflowBarcode = _defaultStateOfWorkflowBarcode.shareIn(viewModelScope, replay = 1,started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed())
```

Fragment:

```
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            viewModel.defaultStateOfWorkflowBarcode.collectLatest {
                it?.let { list->
                    if(list.size == 1)
                        viewModel.getStateOfWorkflowByBarcode(list.first())
                    else if(list.isNotEmpty())
                        openStateOfWorkflowSelectionDialog()
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of helper functions in my project to help work with `StateFlow`s. I think this one might be the one you're looking for:

```
fun <T1, T2, R> CoroutineScope.combineState(
    flow1: StateFlow<T1>,
    flow2: StateFlow<T2>,
    sharingStarted: SharingStarted = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
    transform: (T1, T2) -> R
): StateFlow<R> = combine(flow1, flow2) { f1, f2 ->
    transform.invoke(f1, f2)
}.stateIn(this, sharingStarted, transform.invoke(flow1.value, flow2.value))
```

Usage example:

```
val _defaultStateOfWorkflowBarcode = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.combineState(
        _selectedMachineComponent,
        _defaultStateOfWorkflowBarcode
    ) { machineComponent, previousManufacture ->
        // Map to your new type here
    }
```

This utility function can be generalised to three, four etc. arguments pretty easily as needed. You might find a different `SharingStarted` parameter is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it isn't that I am searchin for, bacuse it returns with a StateFlow, not SharedFlow